# PHP, json_decode, array issue

Tags: php, json

I have a multi-dimensional associative array that is encoded into JSON for database storage, and then decoded for display. I am having trouble accessing the resulting array elements.

An example JSON string:

```
{
    "service": "Star Break Repair",
    "options": {
        "Buy with me -60": "-60.00",
        "Bulseye Break Repair": "30.00"
    }
}
```

After decoding this using `json_decode($array, true)` (true gets an array, not an object), I get  an array as expected:

```
Array
(
    [service] => Star Break Repair
    [options] => Array
        (
            [Buy with me -60] => -60.00
            [Bulseye Break Repair] => 30.00
        )

)
```

But when I try and echo a specific element:

```
echo @key($services['options'][0]);
```

or

```
echo $services['options'][0];
```

I get nothing, blank.

When I try to:

```
key($services['options'][0])
```

I get this error:

```
key() [function.key]: Passed variable is not an array or object in...
```

I've tried saving the options array as its own PHP variable, and the same thing happens. I can `print_r()` either array (the original with the nested options array, or just the options array), but when I try and print a specific element, nothing happens. When I try and print the element key, I get that PHP error.

What's going on?

Comment: I thought for some reason there was a way to access associative array elements via an index integer. Oh well. Ended up doing a foreach on the array anyways. Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you have an associative array for your `options`, not an integer-indexed array.

So, if you want to access the elements of `options` you need to refer to them by their string keys:

```
$foo = $services['options']['Buy with me -60'];
$bar = $services['options']['Bulseye Break Repair'];
```

Now, if you don't know the keys, you can use a foreach loop to iterate over your options array:

```
foreach($services['options'] as $okey=>$oval) {
    echo $okey; //'Buy with me -60', 'Bulseye Break Repair'
    echo $oval; //'-60.00', '30.00'
}
```

Comment: This is ultimately how I did it. I thought for some reason there was a way to access associative array elements via an index integer. Oh well.

Comment: This answer looks eerily similar to an earlier answer.

Comment: @nickb Not sure what you're implying here. I got the notification that answers were posted while I was writing my answer, but obviously I didn't get to see them until after I posted mine. So if you're implying that I rehashed an earlier answer I'd strongly suggest that you reconsider your position.

Comment: @nickb If you are in fact implying that I cribbed your answer, it's likely worth noting that I posted my answer 2 minutes before you updated yours.

Answer (score 3):

This key doesn't exist:

```
echo $services['options'][0];
```

Use:

```
echo $services['options']['Buy with me -60'];
echo $services['options']['Bulseye Break Repair'];
```

**Edit:** To print the elements in `$services['options']` without knowing their keys, just use a foreach loop:

```
foreach( $services['options'] as $key => $value)
{
    echo $value;
}
```

Comment: How do I print those elements without knowing the keys and without a foreach loop? They will always be changing.

Comment: @AVProgrammer You can loop through them using a `foreach($services['options'] as $key => $value)`

Comment: @AVProgrammer - I've updated my answer with a loop that prints the values regardless of the key.

Comment: `var_dump(array_keys($arr['options']));`

Comment: @AVProgrammer You could do `foreach ($services['options'] as $key => value) echo "$key: $value<br />\n";` to print all of them, or `echo $services['options'][key($services['options'])];` to print the one at which the array pointer currently resides.

Comment: @nickb Eerily similar indeed. I just got the chills... ;)

Answer (score 1):

I would just use foreach like others posted, but this seems kinda what you were trying to do.

```
echo key($services['options']);
next($services['options']);
echo key($services['options']);
```

Each array has a hidden position pointer, and those old array iterator functions like key() current() reset() next() etc... use and modify it.
Nobody really uses those old array iterator functions anymore since php 4 introduced the foreach construct, which was a long time ago...

Answer (score 0):

Check the way you're accessing elements

```
<?php

$foo = '{"service":"Star Break Repair","options":{"Buy with me -60":"-60.00","Bulseye Break Repair":"30.00"}}';

$arr = json_decode($foo, true);

var_dump($arr);

echo $arr['options']['Bulseye Break Repair']; //30.00
```